# PHP check whether property exists in object or class

Tags: php, class, variables, object, parameters

I understand PHP does not have a pure object variable, but I want to check whether a property is in the given object or class.

```
$ob = (object) array('a' => 1, 'b' => 12);
```

or

```
$ob = new stdClass;
$ob->a = 1;
$ob->b = 2;
```

In **JS,** I can write this to check if variable `a` exists in an object:

```
if ('a' in ob)
```

In **PHP,** can anything like this be done?

Comment: Just mentioning... when we do OOP, we say property not variable, like we say method, not function.

Answer (score 416, accepted):

#### property_exists( mixed $class , string $property )

```
if (property_exists($ob, 'a'))
```

---

#### isset( mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )

**NOTE** : Mind that **isset() will return false if property is null**

```
if (isset($ob->a))
```

---

Example 1:

```
$ob->a = null
var_dump(isset($ob->a)); // false
```

Example 2:

```
class Foo
{
   public $bar = null;
}

$foo = new Foo();

var_dump(property_exists($foo, 'bar')); // true
var_dump(isset($foo->bar)); // false
```

Comment: Not necessarily, if the property exists, but is not defined isset() will return false.
http://us3.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: isset() can be combined with empty() to check both property **and** value.

Comment: While isset() is the wrong answer, if you are aware of the caveat it is is considerably faster than property_exists()

Comment: is this a situation where `empty()` is a better solution? `!empty($var)` ?

Comment: @b_dubb no, empty array, 0, false, null, '' all return true by `empty()'

Comment: what does @user1050825 mean by not defined? Can someone give an example? I just tried creating a `new stdClass` and then assigning a property of it a value (after instantiating) and then testing with `isset` which returned correctly `true`. Same for normal class definition

Comment: @PetarVasilev see Example 2. `isset($class->bar)` returns false for both `public $bar;` and `public $bar = null;` while `property_exists` returns true for `public $bar = null;`

Answer (score 78):

To check if the property exists and if it's null too, you can use the function `property_exists()`.

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php

As opposed with isset(), property_exists() returns TRUE even if the property has the value NULL.

> bool property_exists ( mixed $class , string $property )

Example:

```
if (property_exists($testObject, $property)) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer since it answers the explicit answer very precise. isset is not useful for testing existence of a property in an object.

Comment: However property_exists return true if the property is declared but not defined (so in fact, is not yet existing).

Answer (score 20):

Neither *isset* or *property_exists* work for me.

- *isset* returns false if the property exists but is NULL.
- *property_exists* returns true if the property is part of the object's class definition, even if it has been unset.

I ended up going with:

```
    $exists = array_key_exists($property, get_object_vars($obj));
```

Example:

```
    class Foo {
        public $bar;

        function __construct() {
            $property = 'bar';

            isset($this->$property); // FALSE
            property_exists($this, $property); // TRUE
            array_key_exists($property, get_object_vars($this)); // TRUE

            unset($this->$property);

            isset($this->$property); // FALSE
            property_exists($this, $property); // TRUE
            array_key_exists($property, get_object_vars($this)); // FALSE

            $this->$property = 'baz';

            isset($this->$property); // TRUE
            property_exists($this, $property); // TRUE
            array_key_exists($property, get_object_vars($this));  // TRUE
        }
    }
```

Comment: property_exist + unset property maybe cause buggy behaviour. This seems to be the safest method

Comment: array_key_exists() is Deprecated in php 7.4

Comment: The keyword in "Using array_key_exists() on objects is deprecated" is objects. get_object_vars() returns an array, so we're still good.

Comment: @Ali_Hr
Don't know where you saw it in the docs.
array_key_exists isn't deprecated in PHP 7.4.

Comment: @Thanh Trung
Why do you want to unset a class property?
property_exists works like expected.
If you unset a class property it is internal set to null.
Regarding the docs property_exists also returns true if the property is null.
So I'm confused what you expected.
Also mentionable that property_exist didn't work if the magical method __get is implemented.

Answer (score 18):

**Solution**

`echo $person->middleName ?? 'Person does not have a middle name';`

To show how this would look in an if statement for more clarity on how this is working.

```
if($person->middleName ?? false) {
    echo $person->middleName;
} else {
    echo 'Person does not have a middle name';
}
```

**Explanation**

The traditional PHP way to check for something's existence is to do:

```
if(isset($person->middleName)) {
    echo $person->middleName;
} else {
    echo 'Person does not have a middle name';
}
```

OR for a more class specific way:

```
if(property_exists($person, 'middleName')) {
    echo $person->middleName;
} else {
    echo 'Person does not have a middle name';
}
```

These are both fine in long form statements but in ternary statements they become unnecessarily cumbersome like so:

`isset($person->middleName) ? echo $person->middleName : echo 'Person does not have a middle name';`

You can also achieve this with just the ternary operator like so:

`echo $person->middleName ?: 'Person does not have a middle name';`

But... if the value does not exist (is not set) it will raise an `E_NOTICE` and is not best practise. If the value is `null` it will not raise the exception.

Therefore ternary operator to the rescue making this a neat little answer:

`echo $person->middleName ?? 'Person does not have a middle name';`

Comment: The "Elvis operator" (`?:`) does NOT check if the property exists!  And `??` is the null coalescing operator.

Comment: @mickmackusa if you had actually read my description you would see that I had mentioned that about `?:`.

Comment: I guess I don't see any reason to mention `?:` on this page, since the title explicitly says: `PHP check whether property exists in object or class`

Answer (score 4):

To check if something exits, you can use the PHP function isset() [see php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). This function will check if the variable is set and is not NULL.

Example:

```
if(isset($obj->a))
{ 
  //do something
}
```

If you need to check if a property exists in a class, then you can use the build in function [property_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php)

Example:

```
if (property_exists('class', $property)) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know if a property exists in an *instance* of a class that you have defined, simply combine `property_exists()` with `isset()`.

```
public function hasProperty($property)
{
    return property_exists($this, $property) && isset($this->$property);
}
```

Comment: Calling `property_exists($this, $property)` is kind of redundant here, since your code will always have the same result as `isset($this->$property)` alone.

Comment: This is a more complete examination of the facts because `isset()` cannot tell you if a property is a true member of the class definition. I will look up again later to make sure.

Comment: That is true, the output will be the same for actual class properties. If you have virtual properties with `__get()` and more importantly `__isset()` magic methods, the output will be different in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

Usually I use kind of custom helper

```php
    /**
     * @param Object $object
     * @param string $property as a string with nested properties 'prop1.nesterdProp.deepvalue'
     * @param mixed $default
     * @return mixed
     */
    function getPropertyOrDefault(Object $object, string $property, $default = null)
    {
        $value = $object;
        $path = explode('.', $property);
        foreach ($path as $prop) {
            if (is_object($value) && property_exists($value, $prop)) {
                $value = $value->{$prop};
            } else {
                return $default;
            }
        }
        return $value;
    }
```

Keep in mind that if property is empty you will get empty value and no default value.

BTW the similar helper works in JS as well.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite new, so be sure you are running PHP 8:

```php
$ob?->a
```

[Reference link](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/null-safe-operator)

Comment: It will not check the property exsistence.

Answer (score 2):

Using array_key_exists() on objects is Deprecated in php 7.4

Instead either isset() or property_exists() should be used

reference : [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.deprecated.php)

Answer (score 0):

Just putting my 2 cents here.

Given the following class:

```php
class Foo
{
  private $data;

  public function __construct(array $data)
  {
    $this->data = $data;
  }

  public function __get($name)
  {
    return $data[$name];
  }

  public function __isset($name)
  {
    return array_key_exists($name, $this->data);
  }
}
```

the following will happen:

```php
$foo = new Foo(['key' => 'value', 'bar' => null]);

var_dump(property_exists($foo, 'key'));  // false
var_dump(isset($foo->key));  // true
var_dump(property_exists($foo, 'bar'));  // false
var_dump(isset($foo->bar));  // true, although $data['bar'] == null
```

Hope this will help anyone