# Php error with the name of class on line 227

Tags: php

This code:

```
function CheckOrderStartCount($OrderID)
{
    global $pdo;
    global $layer;
    $apiskey = '';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM orders WHERE OrderID = :OrderID');
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':OrderID' => $OrderID
    ));
    if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
        $row             = $stmt->fetch();
        $start_count     = $row['OrderStartCount'];
        $ServiceOrderAPI = $layer->GetData('services', 'ServiceOrderAPI', 'ServiceID', $row['OrderServiceID']);
        if (empty($row['OrderStartCount']) && !empty($ServiceOrderAPI)) {
            $URL    = str_replace('[OrderID]', $row['OrderAPIID'], $ServiceOrderAPI);
            $URL = str_replace('[apiskey]', $apiskey, $URL);

            $return = $layer->SendCurl($URL);
            $resp   = json_decode($return);
            if (isset($resp) && property_exists($resp, 'start_count')) 
                $start_count = $resp->start_count;
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE orders SET OrderStartCount = :OrderStartCount WHERE OrderID = :OrderID');
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':OrderStartCount' => $start_count,
                ':OrderID' => $OrderID
            )); 
        }
        return $start_count; 
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
public function DeclarePrice($ProductPrice, $ProductDefaultQuantity, $ProductQuantity)
{
    $ProductValue = $ProductPrice / $ProductDefaultQuantity;
    return $ProductValue * $ProductQuantity;
}
```

Error "First parameter must either be an object or the name of an existing class on line 227":
 if (isset($resp) && property_exists($resp, 'start_count'))

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, what is $resp, and is it appropriate for that function? You shoudl debug your code to find out, and research the API you are using. Related, if not the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14414379/1531971

Comment: By default `json_decode` returns either an object or and array of objects. The problem is that `$resp` doesn't seem to be an object nor a class name, so it must be an array of objects. Do a `print_r` of the `$resp` variable to see its contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
$resp   = json_decode($return);
if (isset($resp) && property_exists($resp, 'start_count'))
```

The error message you are getting implies that $resp is not an object. After reading the documentation for http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php - you will probably notice that it says `Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type`. So why are you getting the error?

```
First parameter must either be an object or the name of an existing class on line 227
```

This must be because **your json is not an object but a scalar (int, bool, array, etc)** of some sort. This could be as simple as `$return` being set to "1", which will return an `int` and not an object. Check `$return` for the source of your error.