# checking if meta tag exists or not before declaring variable with php

Tags: php, tags, meta

i have all the curl and everything retrieving the og properties the problem i have is everything i try to make sure the tag actually exists or not isnt working.
 I get the image tag like so

```
    if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:image')
```

how can i tell if the getAttribute actually exists before i create the variable like so

```
         $img = $meta->getAttribute('content');
```

everything i try just throws php errors

ok here is copy of my complete code

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 
 Firefox/27.0'; 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}

$html = file_get_contents_curl($location);

//parsing begins here:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

//get and display what you need:
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

 $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

 for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
 {
$meta = $metas->item($i);

if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
    $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');

if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
    $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');

if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:image') 
$img = $meta->getAttribute('content');
 }
```

ok let me re explain my problem i get the image but if the image meta tag doesnt exist it throws an error i have tried isset i have tried null i have tried so many things i cant even remember them all

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data you want to parse, and how you process it (I suppose DomDocument ?). It is difficult to help you with so few information.

Comment: Have a look at this might help with what you trying to do [PHP check whether property exists in object or class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414379/php-check-whether-property-exists-in-object-or-class).

Comment: ok i have edited the code to show all of what i have right now.

Comment: ok im trying to see if the image attribute exists if not then i want to replace it with a placeholder image i have even tried hasAttribute